# Get the value of a non-display member item in a ComboBox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox, populate

Hope this isn't too much of a dumb question.

I'm populating a `ComboBox` from MySQL like this:

```vb
Try
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(main.connection_string)
    Dim dax As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,friendly_name FROM     customers WHERE active=1 ORDER BY friendly_name ASC", con)
    Dim dtx As New DataTable
    dax.Fill(dtx)

    ticket_cust_combo.DisplayMember = "friendly_name"
    ticket_cust_combo.DataSource = dtx
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

That works great and the `ComboBox` is populated.

I can retrieve the value of whatever the user has selected with:

```
Dim selectedcust = ticket_cust_combo.text
```

What I'm trying to do is grab the 'id' that's associated with that 'friendly_name'. In my initial SQL read, I read in the 'id' and there is no error, so am I right in assuming it's in some kind of array and the `ComboBox` is using only the `DisplayMember`?

I am making a second SQL call at the minute to go off and retrieve the 'id' again, but that's so wasteful if the data is already here.

Comment: Map the id as the `ValueMember` then look at `SelectedValue`

Comment: Will i retrieve it then with 'blahblah = ticket_cust_combo.value'  ?

Answer (score 0):

Plutonix is exactly right!

added the id as a valuemember like so...

```
 ticket_cust_combo.ValueMember = "id"
```

and can retrieve the ID with...

```
 Dim idval As String = ticket_cust_combo.SelectedValue.ToString
 MessageBox.Show(idval)
```

Thanks, as always :)